# Why do I see return value in new Promise creation block

Tags: javascript

I am puzzled at what's the difference (if any) and use case between the 2. Why would anyone return a value?

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
   return setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('Success')
   }, 2000);
});

p1.then((successVal) => console.log(successVal))
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
   setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('Success')
   }, 2000);
});

p1.then((successVal) => console.log(successVal))
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

**EDIT: Included the below code which is what I actually see.**

```
someFunc = (params) => {
        if (!params) {
            throw new Error('Invalid params');
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return someOtherFunc(params, result => { // why return here? Does it matter? 
                resolve(result);
            }, (code, message, error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    };
```

From what I understand, `someFunc` is a function that will return a `Promise` which will get resolved sometime later by `someOtherFunc`. Why would the return value of `someOtherFunc` matter then? Since its job is to just call the `resolve` or `reject` handler?

Comment: My understanding is that the return value from the executor is ignored, so returning a value (in this case a timeout ID) is pointless and the two versions have the same result.

Comment: that first block of code is probably a result of someone seeing a transpiled version of `const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('Success'), 2000));` and not understanding the first return is NOT required

Comment: The `return` you're asking about in the code that you added in your edit is ignored, the same as in your original example. It makes no difference where `new Promise()` was called from.

Comment: @nnnnnn I see, so it's just some bad code that confused me.

Comment: @NgHuiXiong The code at updated Question would have an issue if the error was thrown within `if` statement, as the function would no longer return a `Promise`

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical difference. The arrow function which you pass to Promise is called [executor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and the value it returns is simply ignored. The values returned in `resolve` and `reject` are the ones that matter.

Comment: `The values returned in resolve and reject` ... you mean `The values passed to resolve and reject` ... because calling `resolve()` and `reject()` return undefined too :p

Comment: Updated my question, not sure if it changes anything.

Comment: Same thing, the return inside `Promise` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand, `someFunc` is a function that will return a
>   `Promise`

Not necessarily the code at updated Question, which will not return a `Promise` if the `if` condition evaluates to `true` and an `Error()` is thrown

```js
const someFunc = (params) => {
  if (!params) {
    throw new Error('Invalid params');
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(123)
  });
};

someFunc()
.then(data => console.log(data)
// what happened to our error handling?
, err => console.error("err:", err.message));
```

The `if` condition should be within `Promise` executor function and the error could possibly be passed to `reject()` with second parameter to `.then()` et or `.catch()` used to handle the possible error

```js
const someFunc = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!params) {
      throw new Error('Invalid params');
    }
    resolve(123);
  });
};

someFunc()
.then(data => console.log(data)
// handle error thrown within `Promise` constructor
, err => console.error("err:", err.message));
```

Comment: Interesting observation that was overlooked. What's more interesting is that it was not caught by TypeScript complier. I was using TypeScript to define this function.

Comment: That is the only significant issue at code at updated Question, which was omitted from original Question; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Have no experience using TypeScript. Perhaps file an issue with the authors of TypeScript indicating that particular pattern, if such a pattern is intended to be "caught" by TypeScript?

Comment: Come to think of it, there wasn't any bug in TypeScript complier. When we throw an error, nothing needs to be returned. In this context, like what you have stated, we should have properly meant to throw the error inside the new `Promise` creation block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating the new Promise within a variable then there is no reason for a return. The only reason why you would want to return something is within a function. You would use the return to have a return value attached to that function.

Comment: The return value from the arrow function the OP asked about is definitely ignored by the `Promise()` constructor.

Comment: Ahh interesting, what I witness was a new `Promise` being returned from a function. Have updated my question.